# Uniform_real_distribution between 0.0 and 1.0 generates extremely low numbers in C++ always close to 0

Tags: c++, random

Inside a class, I am trying to implement a method that generates a random number which would end up being a property of the class. I am calling the method randomPropertyGenerator inside the object constructor.

My minimum code for reproducing the issue looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

class Object {
    public:
        double randomProp;
        double randomPropGen(double a, double b);
        Object() {
            double randomProp = randomPropGen(0.0, 1.0);
        }
};

double Object::randomPropGen(double min, double max){
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(min, max);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine generator(rd());
    return distribution(generator);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine generator(rd());
    
    Object o = Object();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        double randomProp2 = distribution(generator);
        cout << "This is randomProp from object " << o.randomProp << endl;
        cout << "This is randomProp2 inside main " << randomProp2 << endl;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code and run it, I am getting the following results:

```
This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.688014


This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.263372


This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.689736


This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.392283


This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.96836


This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.401998


This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.91537


This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.608586


This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.168815


This is randomProp from object 8.35785e-318
This is randomProp2 inside main 0.631994
```

As you can see the randomProp when generated inside the method of my class is always the same and seems to be always extremely close to 0, whereas the randomProp generated in the main class makes more sense. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix the method? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The posted code can't possibly have generated the claimed output, because `randomProp2` is never re-generated. Please post an actual minimal running example showing the issue, and *that example's output*.

Comment: My crystal ball believes that you're not saving the value from that function where you think you are, leaving the member variable uninitialized.

Comment: `randomProp2` in `main` will always have a single value. Please provide a [mre] that actually demonstrates your problem

Comment: also I don't think a new `std::random_device` seed should be created each time you call `randomPropertyGenerator()`...

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We cannot explain output of code we cannot see. What is `Object` ?

Comment: Sorry for the misworded example, I just tried to extract the piece that is causing troubles from the bigger project. I updated the post with a minimum running example, I don't usually work with C++ so I'm trying to figure out exactly how to use some basic things (using randomness is one of them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor:

```
Object() {
    double randomProp = randomPropGen(0.0, 1.0);
}
```

You declare and initialize a local variable called `randomProp`. This local variable only exists inside the constructor. There is a member of same name, but those are two distinct objects, hence the member is uninitialzed. Members can be initialized in the initializer list:

```
Object() : randomProp(randomPropGen(0.0,1.0) {
}
```

The simple rule to remember is: Members are not initialized in the constructors body (instead, either member initializer list, or default initializers, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)).

Comment: Thanks so much! I see my mistake now!